# Корзина для интернет магазина на django

Tags: django

Привет всем. Такая таска: нужно сделать корзину для ИМ на джанго самую элементарную, чтобы при переходе в "Корзину", она выводила таблицу с именем товара, количеством и суммой, а также общей суммой товаров. Создал модели Product(продукт) и Cart(Корзина). Объясните пожалуйста механизм взаимодействия, кто за что цепляется и примеры, если можно.

P.S. Сильно не пинайте пожалуйста, совсем новичок, делаю задание.

Comment: https://github.com/UlugbekMuslitdinov/exizmat
Могу привести в пример код моего интернет-магазина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-cart смотрели?

Comment: Если это оно https://code.google.com/p/django-cart/ , то смотрел. Там нет кода моделей Cart и Product, поэтому я не очень понимаю. И с сессиями тоже не понимаю как, не знаю их. Если можете, объясните доходчиво, пожалуйста

Comment: Есть и Cart, и generic relation на товар https://code.google.com/p/django-cart/source/browse/trunk/cart/models.py

С сессиями все просто - Вы туда что-то кладете в одном запросе, и достаете в другом. Как это работает внутри - неважно сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо. Я могу просто скопировать код или нужно еще в приложениях потом подключать?

Comment: Не надо ничего копировать, просто подключаете django-cart, там же пример есть

Comment: Не могу найти пример

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/django-cart/ прямо на главной